# How do I integrate .NET core with VS 2017, or will it come by default with VS 2017?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

i am trying to learn .net core with VS 2017. i dont have any basic idea about .NET Core development. Can any one suggest how can i start my first sample development in Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: To properly do it you should get VS2019. Newest versions are supported in that only. You can use older ones with VS 2017, just install the support into it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually which version of .net core have to install, and tooling Preview software what version will support for 2017.  Am searching in google, information was displaying about Vs2019 only.

Comment: Visual Studio Installer has it all in it. Just select it from there and it’ll install it for you

Answer (score 0):

To start with ASP.NET core, you must have visual studio 2017 installed and download the .Net Core SDK from: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core. I recommend that you download version 2.2 for VS 2017.

And have the web development package installed through Visual Studio Installer.

But, it would be better if you already started your studies with the VS 2019.following the same steps above.

VS 2019 already comes with SDKS for .Net core development